# PHPMailer with anti-flood protection?

Tags: phpmailer

I use currently swiftmailer 6.3.0 which have a [anti-flood plugin](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/plugins.html#antiflood-plugin) or newer SymfonyMailer use ["restart_threshold" or "max_per_second"](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#other-options). Is there something similar in [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)? In the [documentation](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/) I found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That’s an app-level concern outside of PHPMailer’s scope. Most app frameworks (e.g. Laravel) have rate limit controls to do this kind of thing. Alternatively, implement sending rate limits in your local mail server, which will be far more efficient than anything you can do in PHP.